# Picasso loading drawable-night only

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have been trying to figure out a way to make Picasso load drawable because I want something different.

I figured out the way and this is what I am using,

```
        String logoSym;
        logoSym = datum.getSymbol().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

        Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.package/drawable/" + logoSym);
        Picasso.get().load(otherPath).into(holder.logoId);
```

Now the problem is, I have drawable and drawable-night. Also I am using Shared Prefences as in my app settings, I made an option there to switch between Dark and Light mode.

So the problem is, If the drawable I am trying to load in Picasso have its -night version too in drawable-night. The drawable will only be loaded in night mode and if I switch back to light mode. There will be no drawable loaded.

But if I will delete the night version of it from drawable-night. Then the light version will be loaded in light mode and the night mode too.

Please help me out, I have no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the error code?

Picasso allows you to use an image as error (in case the intended image is not loaded properly) like:

```
    Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.package/drawable/" + logoSym);
    Picasso.get().load(otherPath).error(R.drawable.image).into(holder.logoId);
```

Be careful that in the error(...), an Integer value is acceptable, such error(R.drawable.image)